# Calculate SQL Age for Latest item with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I'm working with the following table below:

```
ID    Status        DateStamp    Stopper         Age
BA1   In-Progress   05/01/2019   New                 
BA2   Open          01/01/2019   New             
BA2   In-progress   03/01/2019   New             What is the age?
BA4   Closed        04/01/2019   Do_Not_Use
BA1   In-Progress   01/01/2019   New             What is the age?
```

How can I calculate the age for the latest unique Identifier as long as the following conditions are met:

1. Stopper does not equal "Do_Not_User"
2. The status has changed

Comment: Latest? Isn't the 05/01/2019 row the latest one?

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Hi Jarlh in this case because BA1 status hasn't changed it's not considered the latest, but in the case of BA2 the status changes so the 03/01/2019 is considered the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following what you are trying to do, this should work for you. Essentially, a couple of CTE's are used to get the end result. The first is used to ensure you calculate against the earliest date per ID and Status combination, along with filtering out the DO_NOT_USE records.

The second CTE is responsible for partitioning the the results of the first CTE by the datestamp as well as performing the age calculations.

All that's left is selecting from the final CTE where the PartID = 1

```
--GROUP BY ID AND STATUS TO ELIMINATE ROWS THAT DON'T HAVE A CHANGED STATUS. USE MIN DATE
--EXLCUDE ROWS WITH STOPPER VALUE OF 'DO_NOT_USE'
;with initFilter
AS
(
    SELECT ID, [Status], MIN(DateStamp) as DateStamp
    FROM @data
    WHERE Stopper != 'Do_Not_Use'
    GROUP By ID, [Status]

),
--FURTHER REFINE BY PARTITIONING BY ID, IN ORDER OF DATESTAMP
--ADD IN THE DATE DIFF TO CALCULATE AGE
ageCalc
AS
(
    SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateStamp) as PartID
    , DATEDIFF(year, DateStamp, GETDATE()) as AgeInYears
    , DATEDIFF(day, DateStamp, GETDATE()) as AgeInDays
    FROM initFilter
)

--RETURN ALL ROWS WITH A PARTID OF 1
SELECT ID, Status, DateStamp, AgeInYears, AgeInDays
FROM ageCalc
WHERE PartID = 1
```

Comment: Hi Aaron this looks like what I'm trying to do, just a couple of quick questions, initFilter is that the name of the table?

Comment: _initFilter_ is just the name I gave to the cte. The table you select from is referenced inside of the _initFilter_ cte. In the example it is `@data` (I used a table variable for testing). _ageCalc_ is another cte with an arbitrary name. I've used _initFilter_ inside of the _ageCalc_ cte and then finally selected from _ageCalc_.

Answer (score 3):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*, 
      (case when seq = 1 then datediff(year, getdate(), datestamp) end) as age
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by datestamp desc) as seq
      from table t
      where stopper <> 'do_not_use'
     ) t;
```

`datediff()` is for SQL Server, but you didn't tag any dbms. So, other database has different syntax for calculating age.

Comment: @Kevin. . .  Thanks.

Comment: @YogeshSharma  thank this works for calculating the age for the latest ID, but in the case of BA1 since the status didn't change I need the previous age to continue, can you guys help?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this, but I think this will get you what you need:

```
with mostCurrent as (
    select id, max(DateStamp)  as MaxDateStamp from table1
    where stopper <> 'Do_Not_Use'
    group by id
),
mcValues as (
select t.* from table1 t
inner join MostCurrent mc on t.id = mc.id and t.dateStamp = mc.MaxDateStamp
),
nextMostCurrent as(
select t.id, max(t.DateStamp) as MaxDateStamp from table1 t
inner join mostCurrent on t.id = mostCurrent.id and t.DateStamp < mostCurrent.MaxDateStamp
where t.stopper <> 'do_not_use'
group by t.id
),
nmcValues as (
select t.* from table1 t
inner join nextMostCurrent nmc on t.id = nmc.id and t.dateStamp = nmc.MaxDateStamp
)

Select nmcv.*, datediff(day,nmcv.DateStamp,getdate()) AS AgeInDays
from nmcValues nmcv
inner join mcValues mcv on nmcv.ID = mcv.Id
where nmcv.Status<>mcv.Status
```